# Loop through ACF taxonomies and output associated posts

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a page template that loops through all existing post categories and outputs 5 associated posts for each category. I want to change this so it only outputs the categories I have selected in an ACF Taxonomy field on a particular page.

I have set up the page and added the ACF Taxonomy field to this, however I can't work out how to get the original loop to only use the taxonomies selected here. What's the best way to achieve this?

I've tried passing the taxonomies via `get_field('taxonomy_field_name')` into the first foreach, however that doesn't seem to be working

Here's how I'm looping through the categories/posts:

```
<?php 
/* Loop through Categories and Display Posts */
    $post_type = 'post';
    // Get all the taxonomies for this post type
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
      $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
      foreach( $terms as $term ) :
          $args = array(
                  'post_type' => $post_type,
                  'posts_per_page' => 5,  //show all posts
                  'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                          'field' => 'slug',
                          'terms' => $term->slug,
                      )
                  )
              );
          $posts = new WP_Query($args); ?>
          <div class="category-container-row">
          <?php if( $posts->have_posts() ): ?> 
            <div class="category-title">
                <h2>
                    <?php echo '<a href="' . get_site_url() . '/' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';?>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="post-listing-row carousel-container">
            <?php while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="single-post">
                  <h3>
                  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php  echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
                  </h3>
              </article>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach;
    endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you already have, and what you've attempted,

Comment: Apologies, that's added now

Comment: Where do you get data from your ACF field ? we can not see that on the code u just put above. And in the tax_query, you'r passing an object **'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,** instead of the name of your taxonomy! **'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name,**

Answer (score 1):

The ACF "Taxonomy" field lets you select *terms* from a taxonomy, not taxonomies themselves. So if you want your selections in that field to be used in your code, you need to:

1. Remove the `get_object_taxonomies()` line and the subsequent `foreach`. You're looping through terms, not Taxonomies,
2. Make sure the Taxonomy field is set to return *Term ID*. As the primary key, this is likely faster than querying posts by term slugs.
3. Replace `get_terms()` with the `get_field()` for your custom field. This is what you'll be looping over.
4. Change your `tax_query` to use `term_id` as the field, to match the output of the field as set in #2.

That will leave you with something like this:

```
$post_type = 'post';
$taxonomy  = 'taxonomy_name';
$terms     = get_field( 'taxonomy_field_name' );

foreach( $terms as $term ) :
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $term,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Output posts, etc.

endforeach;
```

Comment: Amazing, that's sorted it, thanks for your help